# Why am I unable to get the contacts from my phone with Cordova's Contacts API?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building a phone app with Phonegap well, actually with Steroids.js which is built on top of Phonegap. Right now, all I want to do is retrieve the list of contact names and numbers from my phone upon the launching of my app. I took a look at the [Contacts](http://docs.appgyver.com/en/stable/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts) api here and I thought I was using it correctly. Below is the script I have inside of my head tags. What have I done wrong?

```
<script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 // Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
            options.filter = "";
            var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
            navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
function onSuccess(contacts) {
alert('ons');
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

               //trying to display contacts in an alert message when I launch my app

               alert("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
            }
        }

        // onError: Failed to get the contacts

        function onError(contactError) {
            alert('onError!');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: it is working fine for me..able to receive my contacts..

Comment: Put cordova.js in `assets/www` folder  change cordova file include like to `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code your `cordova.js` file is misplaced somewhere.
like

```
<script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
```

You need to copy that cordova.js file into `assest/www/` folder (like `assest/www/cordova.js)`

so it becomes like below in your html file

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```