# PhoneGap Camera , Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to get the Camera API to work in my PhoneGap android app, but i keep getting this error

> "Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined".

Now i have checked countless answers on StackOverflow and tutorials all over the web,and tried all the answer there(with no luck), and i cant seem to find the issue.

This is the button that calls the function

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getPic()">Camera</button>
```

This is the controller that handles the camera

```
myApp.controller('EditProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $http, navigateFactory) {
$scope.getPic = function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 60,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: 1
    });
    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed beause' + message);
    }
};
});
```

Please comment if there is any additional information required.
Any and all help will be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: So after following Aravin's advice i added `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`
now it atleast looks like something is happening, but now im getting these errors in my eclipse logcat:

> I/System.out(3871): Error adding plugin
>   org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher  D/PluginManager(3871): exec() call
>   to unknown plugin: Camera

Comment: Are you running in simulator or mobile device?

Comment: Well both, on the device nothing happens at all, on the browser i get that error

Comment: In browser, you will get this "undefined" error. because phonegap API's will work only when you wrap it as a build(ipa,apk..).

Comment: show where your cordova.js is located

Comment: Where would cordova.js usually be... sorry , i am working on this as part of a team so i didnt do everything myself

Comment: cordova.js should be inside www folder like www/cordova.js for cordova version 3 and above..

Comment: @msg i still get the undefined error when on the device, from the eclipse LogCat : /Web Console(1434): ReferenceError: Camera is not defined
07-08 12:35:39.655: E/Web Console(1434):     at Object.$scope.getPic (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:167:30)

Comment: @Aravin Just looked for it, i dont seem to have it :/ ... that cant be good ??

Comment: @unselected can't get you..

Comment: ah wait , is the cordova.js that inside the platforms/www ? or should that file be in the main www dir ?

Comment: @unselected check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544117/why-am-i-unable-to-get-the-contacts-from-my-phone-with-cordovas-contacts-api/24545284#24545284

Comment: @unselected are you add the camera api plugin or not?

Comment: @Aravin I added the plugin with the cli ...cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

Comment: ok good. Added the necessary permissions in manifest

Comment: its already added , if android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is what ur referring too.

Comment: Note to self: naming a service Camera has a high risk of conflicting with those constants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying all the things here with no success I did this which fixed the issue (dont know how)...
remove the plugin , build , add the plugin , build
and Magic!

Comment: I have the same mistake. Could you explain what you did? If you can edit your answer in more detail, you can help others.

Answer (score 2):

The total work around is below..

you need to write all code in your html page.

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page"> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getPhotoFromCamera() { 
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
                quality: 50, 
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            }); 
        } 
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData){ 
            var image = document.getElementById('image'); 
            image.style.display = 'block'; 
            image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData; 
        } 
        function getPhotoFromAlbum(){ 
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail,{ 
                quality: 50, 
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, 
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI 
            }); 
        } 
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI){ 
            var image = document.getElementById('image'); 
            image.style.display = 'block'; 
            image.src = imageURI; 
        } 
        function onFail(message){ 
            alert('Failed because:' + message); 
        } 
        </script> 

        <div data-role="header" style="height:36px;"> 
            <h1>Write New</h1> 
            <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a> 
        </div> 

        <button onclick="getPhotoFromCamera();">Launch Camera</button> 
        <button onclick="getPhotoFromAlbum();">Goto Picture Gallery</button> 
        <div> 
            <img id="image" style="display:none;width;290px;height:210px;" src = ""/> 
        </div> 

    </div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS, remember to check out for edit "fetch.json" before installing the plugin, or it will fail mid-installation.